# How do I create a selection form on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am trying to create a form that displays multiple options of how to display data on a map based on different spans of time (day of week, time of day...). I would like to save the options the user inputs from the form using Ruby on Rails but am unaware of how to create a form using the select tag. I have the code in html as of now but would like to convert it into Ruby on Rails so I can abstract the values inputed by the user easily in order to display the correct data. This is the code I have

```
    <!-- SPAN OF TIME--> 
                         <strong>Span:</strong>
                         <select id="span" class="span2">
                                <option>Today</option>
                                <option>This Week</option>
                                <option>This Month</option>
                                <option>This Year</option>
                            </select>
                            </br> 



                        <!-- WEEKDAY --> 
                        <strong>Weekday:</strong>
                            <select id="weekday" class="span2">
                                <option>All days</option>
                                <option>Weekend</option>
                                <option>Weekdays</option>
                                <option>Sunday</option>
                                <option>Monday</option>
                                <option>Tuesday</option>
                                <option>Wednesday</option>
                                <option>Thursday</option>
                                <option>Friday</option>
                                <option>Saturday</option>
                            </select>
                            </br> 

                        <!-- WEEKDAY --> 
                        <strong>Time of Day:</strong>
                            <select id="time" class="span2">
                                <option>Morning</option>
                                <option>Afternoon</option>
                                <option>Night</option>
                            </select>
                        </br> 


                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Show Data</button>
```

Comment: You want to have a text_input field and then save what the users types and put the value into a dropdown select box?

Comment: I have the values already for the drop down menus. I would like to display the data based on the values they choose

Comment: So are you looking to parse the parameters that the user sends from the select form?

Comment: yes I would like to parse the params

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation that answers your question:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

Your option tags need to have a value attribute. The option value is what is submitted to the controller. You will then be able to access this data through the params hash. I would also suggest using rails form helpers to generate these tags dynamically.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags